# Text is different size on different platforms

Tags: css, fonts, firefox4, directwrite

How do I get precise sizing on different platforms, if each platform renders text at a different size? This issue was exacerbated with the recent release of [Firefox 4](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/fx/). This version enables hardware rendering of text using [DirectWrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite). The size of the text written with DirectWrite is much taller than text written with no hardware acceleration. Note the following example. Here's the [live example](http://www.veetle.com/index.php/broadcast/beta) if you need to see the 
CSS.

[image: directwrite off]

- Windows 7 64-bit Home
- ATI Radeon HD 4670
- DirectWrite is **off** because my drivers are not updated.
- 620 x 283

[image: directwrite on]

- Windows Vista 64-bit Business
- nVidia GeForce 8800GT
- DirectWrite is **on** because I just updated my drivers.
- 620 x 293

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li><a>Nav</a></li>
 <li><a>Nav</a></li>
 <li><a>Nav</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
 Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
 float: left;
 width: 10em;
}

div {
 margin: 0 0 0 12.7em;
 min-height: 26.1em;
}
```

Do you see how the navigation lines up with the content when DirectWrite is off, but the navigation is taller than the content when DirectWrite is on? I know there are some hacky solutions. One is to specify everything (`font-size, width, height`) in px. This is not ideal because the component will not be modular - that is, it can't be re-used in another setting scaled to another size. It also breaks IE6's font size options. Another solution is to use JavaScript to read the physical height of the navigation and make the content the same height. This is not ideal because it is CSS's role to style. Is there any CSS solution for this?

This is just one of many examples. Another is Firefox 3 on Ubuntu 9 has much wider text, so not all links fit in my primary navigation. I was forced to chop off the last navigation link with `max-width: 37em; overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Is this spam/fishing? When I try to look at the live example, I get a page that says that I need to download some plugin.

Comment: No, the plugin is verified clean by McAfee: http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/veetle.com/summary/ . You don't have to download the plugin to view the HTML/CSS.

Comment: Is that a web frontend to a dedicated encoding box? Nice. :)

Comment: you've gotta be the hottest/strongest programmer of all time

Comment: @JoJo: How could I view the HTML/CSS of the example when I get a download page instead?

Comment: "How do I get precise sizing on different platforms" - you don't, you will never get "precise" - CSS is a suggestion, font-sizing is, always has been, the users prerogative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My honest answer is that you have to deal with different font sizes.  Your best bet is to not align the content-height using `min-height: 26.1em` as it's "hacky".  I'd suggest re-structuring your HTML so that the UL is inside the DIV and the bottom line always matches.

Short of that, you can set `ul li { line-height: 1em }` or similar which will make the LIs always the same height.

Comment: I can't restructure my HTML as suggested, because the content expands when you hit "Advanced options": http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/8954/10628290.png . Setting my line-height to 1em didn't quite work. On the same machine with DirectWrite off, Chrome and Firefox ended up with different heights.

Comment: `li { height : 2.6em; } div { min-height : 26em; }` maybe?

Comment: or something similar... `ul { height : 26.1em; } li { height: 10% }`

Comment: I think you're on the right track. A small detail you missed is that the navigation has a 0.1em border on each <li>, which adds up in the total height.

Comment: This code is consistent in FF and Chrome with DirectWrite off: `ul li { line-height: 2.8em } div { min-height: 26.9em }` as calculated by this formula: *(numPresets * (presetLineHeight + presetBorderBottom)) + presetSelectedBorderTop - this.padding - this.border*. I'll have to wait until I get home to see DirectWrite changes the game. I'm hoping that setting a hard line-height will override DirectWrite's tendency to be taller.

Comment: My borders are 0.1em. It effectively gets translated to 1px. I'd rather keep the units the same for easier calculations. You can't really add px with em.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it. They are essentially different entities and the content isn't fixed anyway, as you said it will expand if you hit "Advanced Options". I think it looks fine going a tad over, as if its letting you know its not a fixed boundary.
Here's an idea. If you wanted to keep it fixed, you can wrap all of that inside a container DIV and use that to define it's borders. Then use overflow scrolling with the content when it expands outside of the container DIV. As long as its vertical, it shouldn't be too much of a bother